# How do computed variables passed to included make files' functions get expanded?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

To reduce the amount of repeated boiler plate in a top level makefile, I created an included make file that uses computed variable names.  Where I'm having difficulty is in the excerpt from the included makefile: `ftp-files.mk`:

```
...
$($(FNMPFX)_FTP_CFG): $(CFG_MAKE_FILE) | $($(FNMPFX)_FTP_CFG_DIR)
    $(call ftp_helper, $@, $($(FNMPFX)_FTP_DIR), $($(FNMPFX)_CACHE_DIR), $($(FNMPFX)_FTP_NAME))
...
```

In the main makefile, I was hoping to do something akin to:

```
CFG_MAKE_FILE := Makefile

define ftp_helper
     echo "quote USER anonymous"      > $(1)
     echo "quote PASS"               >> $(1)
     echo "cd $(2)"                  >> $(1)
     echo "lcd $(3)"                 >> $(1)
     echo "binary"                   >> $(1)
     echo "get $(4)"                 >> $(1)
     echo "quit"                     >> $(1)
endef

FNMPFX := FILE_A
include ftp-files.mk

...

FNMPFX := FILE_Z
include ftp-files.mk
...
```

The trouble is that the order only prerequisite (also tried it as a normal prerequisite) expands to the last ... instanciation (?) of the included file.

What appears to be happening is a first expansion of the two targets that behave as though they were written:

```
#                         Point of confusion V
#                                            |
$(FILE_A_FTP_CFG): $(CFG_MAKE_FILE) | $(FILE_Z_FTP_CFG_DIR)
    $(call ftp_helper, $@, $(FILE_A_FTP_DIR), $(FILE_A_CACHE_DIR), $(FILE_A_FTP_NAME))

$(FILE_Z_FTP_CFG): $(CFG_MAKE_FILE) | $(FILE_Z_FTP_CFG_DIR)
    $(call ftp_helper, $@, $(FILE_Z_FTP_DIR), $(FILE_Z_CACHE_DIR), $(FILE_Z_FTP_NAME))
```

Is this possible?

My work around was to include that simple target rule in the main Makefile (`ftp-file.mk` is reasonably wordy at 100 lines), so having those two lines (repeated) throughout the main Makefile isn't too burdensome.

Can somebody suggest a working alternative?

Comment: There *is* a way to fix this, but... Although you haven't given us a working example, this looks over-designed. Somewhere you must have a long list of definitions of all of these variables. Is there really a good reason to put a variable prefix `FNMPFX` into all of those file and directory names?

Comment: @Beta Not a very helpful comment, particularly since you're assuming the mess of a Makefile system I inherited is mine own design. The question was only written in the first person for brevity.  Yes, overdesigned, but if you have a way to fix this (as you seem to imply), then please, do fess up. (and what's wrong with `FNMPFX`? it reads quite _plainly_ to me as FileName Macro PreFiX :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't read a whole Makefile like a shell script. It's read in multiple phases, and certain things are done with the entire contents of the Makefile before proceeding to the next step. The rules are rather complex, but suffice it to say that it looks like the last assigned value is used:

```
$ cat Makefile 
variable := original

first:
    echo $(variable)

variable := other

second:
    echo $(variable)
$ make first
echo other
other
$ make second
echo other
other
```

Comment: Ah .. well then.  Seems the design pattern is hosed.  Thank you.